# Possibility to create a hidden custom formula in Excel add-in

Tags: office365, ms-office, office-js, office-addins, custom-functions-excel

Is it possible to create a hidden custom formula in Excel add-in? So that when a user typing this formula, the Excel does not show tip, but the formula exists. Maybe there is a property in Functions Metadata such as @hidden?

Comment: Usually tips are always shown when user type a function in Excel. Custom Functions follow the same pattern. May I know what's the scenario is to create a hidden custom functions?

Comment: We need to concatenate all formulas' arguments values in one string. If the formula argument is a reference to a cell, it should be concatenated as a value, not as an address (e.g. the formula is VV("yes", $C$1) and the C1 value is "maybe". The hidden formula concatenates all arguments in the following way "yes, maybe", not "yes, $C$1").
Out team decided that a hidden formula may be created in order to parse the arguments and concatenate them in a described way.